# How to filter a view relating node and user data?

Tags: views, userpoints

I created a content type called **Vouchers**. This content type has a field called: **Points**.

In the other hand I enabled the http://drupal.org/project/Userpoints module which allows users to get points.

I created 2 Vouchers nodes. One of them has the value 10 for the **Points** field and the other one 15

After, I created a view to show the content type: **Vouchers**. Now I need to add a filter to show the vouchers node only if its **Points** field value is lower than the **User points** value (the current logged user)

Please, look my capture to make this understandable:

[image]

Comment: Check this out http://drupal.org/node/1389248. The use case is pretty similar. It uses the flags and rules module to flag content which the user has access to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the same filter programmatically to your view.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view().
 */
function YOURMODULE_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'your_view_machine_name') {
    $info = array(
      'table' => 'field_data_field_points', // name of your “Points” field table.
      'field' => 'field_points_value', // name of value field in that table.
      'value' => array('value' => userpoints_get_current_points()), // dynamic part.
      'operator' => '<',
      'id' => 'field_data_field_points_YOURMODULE', // unique id.
      'group' => 100, // new group.
    );
    $handler = views_get_handler($info['table'], $info['field'], 'filter');

    $handler->init($view, $info);
    $view->display_handler->handlers['filter'][$info['id']] = &$handler;

    unset($handler);
  }
}
```

It will automatically join the table and add condition to query.

Comment: I added an exposed filter and is not shown. If I disable the module I created with your code then it is shown correctly. How can I make your code allow the exposed filter to be shown. Thanks.